# Excel VBA .Find() misbehaving Cannot locate string

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of values on a sheet

E11: "Notional"

E12: "Strike"

E13: "Coupon"

Etc.

In my code, use the sheet name

```
Function AddInput(name As String, strInput As String, Optional suffix = "") As String
Dim inputVal As Variant
On Error GoTo ERROR_FUNCTION
    With Worksheets(name)
        If .Cells.Find(what:=strInput, LookAt:=xlWhole,searchorder:=xlByRows).Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
            inputVal = Trim(Cells.Find(what:=strInput, LookAt:=xlWhole,     searchorder:=xlByRows).Offset(0, 1).Value)
            If TypeName(inputVal) = "Date" Then inputVal = Format(inputVal, "YYYYMMDD")
        AddInput = Replace(strInput, " ", "") & "=" & inputVal & "&"
            If suffix <> "" Then AddInput = AddInput & suffix
        Else
            AddInput = ""
        End If
    End With

Exit Function
ERROR_FUNCTION:
    Debug.Print strInput & ": input not found"
    MsgBox strInput & ": input not found"
End Function
```

I am able to find whats in Cell E12, but not E11.
I have done the following:

1) I copied the cell value into the search function directly (No chance to fat-finger it).

2) I copied the values from E11 down 1 (if for some reason it couldn't find that range etc... it just returned E12).

I still cannot find that one cell, it works for every other value I put through it.

Has anyone encountered this, and how did you resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that Find only finds things in visible cells.

Comment: It is a visible cell.

Comment: @Kelvin The code snippet you posted really doesn't do anything. Your second line is incomplete.  Coupled with the fact that your code doesn't work, I'd say we don't have enough information to tell why, but it is likely due to problems in code you have not yet posted.

Comment: Edited with more code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you start each search correctly:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    strSheetname = ActiveSheet.Name
    MyInputString = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter value", Type:=2)
    With Sheets(strSheetname)
        Set r = .Cells.Find(what:=MyInputString, After:=Range("A1"))
    End With
    MsgBox r.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```